# IF...ELSE with Cypher Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Has there been any update to the syntax of an `IF/ELSE` statement in Cypher?

I know about `CASE` and the `FOREACH` "hacks" but they are so unsightly to read :)

I was wanting to do something with optional parameters such as:

```
CASE WHEN exists($refs.client) THEN MATCH (cl:client {uuid: $refs.client}) END
...

// and later use it like
CASE WHEN exists(cl) THEN DELETE tcr MERGE (t)-[:references]->(cl) END

// and again in my return
RETURN {
  client: CASE WHEN exists(cl) THEN {uuid: cl.uuid} ELSE NULL END,
}
```

I know that doesn't make a lot of sense given the context, but I'm basically passing in a refs object which may or may not contain parameters (or the parameters exist and are NULL)

Somewhere I read there might be an update to how an "if/else" may be handled in neo4j so I really just wanted to check in and see if anyone was aware of a "nicer" way to handle cases like this.

Currently, I just handle all my queries in code and run a bunch of smaller queries, but it requires duplicate lookups for creating and deleting references. I'd like to move it all into one larger query so I can use variable references.

Again, I know I could use `FOREACH...CASE`, but when there is a lot of smaller cases like this, it gets hairy.

Currently the error is

```
{ Error: Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 7, column 9 (offset: 246))
"      CASE true WHEN exists($refs.client) THEN MATCH (cl:client {uuid: $refs.client}) END"
         ^
```

I also know that I can use `WITH...CASE` if I'm passing back a known value, but cannot do a `MATCH` inside it.

One of the reasons for wanting to do `MATCH` inside the `CASE` at the top of the query, is because I want the query to fail if the property on refs exists but the `MATCH` does not succeed. Using `OPTIONAL MATCH` does not accomplish this.

EDIT
Oh, also... I'm reviewing using
`MATCH (cl:client {uuid: $refs.client}) WHERE exists($refs.client)` but I recall that not working correctly.

EDIT
I can do `MATCH...WHERE exists()` but later it's futile if I can't do `MERGE WHERE exists()`

EDIT
For reference to show why I'm asking about an IF/ELSE, here is the query I'm looking at. I've modified it from the above example so it doesn't error out.

```
MATCH (u:user {uuid: $uid})-[:allowed_to {read: true}]->(c:company {uuid: $cid})
MATCH (t:timesheet {uuid: $tid})<-[:owns]-(:timesheets)<-[:owns]-(u)

// Make sure the incoming references are valid or fail query
// Here, I'd like only do a match IF $refs.client exists and IS NOT NULL. If it is null or does not exist, I don't want the query to fail. OPTIONAL MATCH will not fail if the value is passed in is invalid but will simply return NULL. Which is why IF/ELSE (or CASE) would be helpful here.
MATCH (cl:client {uuid: $refs.client})
MATCH (ca:case {uuid: $refs.case})
MATCH (s:step {uuid: $refs.step})
MATCH (n:note {uuid: $refs.note})

// clone timesheet entry to a revision
CREATE (t)-[:assembled_with]->(r:revision)
SET r = t, r.created_at = $data.updated_at

WITH *

// Get the old references
MATCH (t)-[tcr:references]->(rc:client)
MATCH (t)-[tcar:references]->(rca:case)
MATCH (t)-[tsr:references]->(rs:step)
MATCH (t)-[tnr:references]->(rn:note)

// Copy old references to revision (won't create new relationships with NULL)
MERGE (r)-[:references]->(rc)
MERGE (r)-[:references]->(rca)
MERGE (r)-[:references]->(rs)
MERGE (r)-[:references]->(rn)

// Update the current timesheet with new data
SET t += $data

// If new references are incoming, delete the old ones and update for new ones
DELETE tcr
DELETE tcar
DELETE tsr
DELETE tnr
MERGE (t)-[:references]->(cl)
MERGE (t)-[:references]->(ca)
MERGE (t)-[:references]->(s)
MERGE (t)-[:references]->(n)

WITH *

// Get the new count of revisions
MATCH (t)-[:assembled_with]->(_r:revision)

RETURN {
  uuid: t.uuid,
  start: t.start,
  end: t.end,
  description: t.description,
  client: CASE WHEN exists(cl.uuid) THEN {uuid: cl.uuid} ELSE NULL END,
  case: CASE WHEN exists(ca.uuid) THEN {uuid: ca.uuid} ELSE NULL END,
  step: CASE WHEN exists(s.uuid) THEN {uuid: s.uuid} ELSE NULL END,
  note: CASE WHEN exists(n.uuid) THEN {uuid: n.uuid} ELSE NULL END,
  revisions: count(_r)
}
```

Comment: Can you restate this as a single focused question?

Comment: There is only one question. How can I make it anymore single focused? "Has there been any update to the syntax of an IF/ELSE statement in Cypher?" as stated in the first sentence. I'm merely giving what has been tried to eliminate unwanted "suggestions" that don't pertain to my use-case. The first code block shows what I'm trying to accomplish to give some reference where I'm coming from in my request.

Comment: Also, what did you mean by "I want the query to fail if the property on refs exists, but the MATCH does succeed"?

Comment: I'm passing in $refs parameter into the query, let's say, it contains a property called client. In the query, if $refs.client exists and is not null, I want to do a MATCH to find the client by $refs.client. If $refs.client is not passed in or it's null, I don't care about it. However, if $refs.client contains a value, but a MATCH does not match anything, I want the query to fail. For reference, I'll post the larger query in a second to show where IF/ELSE would be helpful.

Comment: So, you meant "but the MATCH does NOT succeed"? If so, please correct your question.

Comment: We're working on adding conditional Cypher execution functionality to APOC, so keep an eye out for that in the near future. I'll try to update with an answer whenever it becomes available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/) just updated with support for [conditional cypher execution](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/conditionals/). You'll need version 3.1.3.7 or greater (if using Neo4j 3.1.x), or version 3.2.0.3 or greater (if using Neo4j 3.2.x).

Here's an example of some of the cases you mentioned, using the new procedures:

```
CALL apoc.when($refs.client IS NOT NULL, 
 "MATCH (cl:client {uuid: refs.client}) RETURN cl", '', {refs:$refs}) YIELD value
WITH value.cl as cl  // which might be null...
...

...
CALL apoc.do.when(cl IS NOT NULL, 
 "DELETE tcr 
  MERGE (t)-[:references]->(cl)", '', {tcr:tcr, t:t, cl:cl}) YIELD value
...

...
RETURN {
  client: cl {.uuid}, ...
}
```

In your return, map projection is enough to meet your needs, you'll get an object with the uuid if `cl` exists, or a null for `client` if not.

Comment: As it's been a number of years and new options for this are available, please refer to my newer answer (referencing our knowledge base article on conditional cypher execution) instead of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Older question, but there are some new tricks to achieve conditional Cypher execution, especially with subqueries introduced in Neo4j 4.1.x.

This knowledge base article covers the options available, and we'll keep the article updated as additional approaches become available.

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/conditional-cypher-execution/

Note that the APOC approach in my older answer is still valid, and included in the article.

Comment: Thanks for posting out the new tricks +1. can you just tell me what's the advantage of using apoc module? Actually I am a noob. I am done with neo4j (cypher) So wanted to know whether I should use apoc for all the problems.

Comment: APOC is a supplemental library. It offers some functionality that is currently impossible with Cypher alone. For other cases, it offers an alternate choice. You can include it and decide when and where to use its functions and procedures.